# Which is the origin of Romanian /h/?

Tags: historical-linguistics, sound-change, romance-languages, romanian

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanian_phonology),

> Romanian has [...] the glottal fricative /h/.

You can hear it, for instance, in the Romanian word [*arhaic*](https://translate.google.com/?sl=ro&tl=en&text=arhaic%0A&op=translate).

This cannot be of Latin origin because, as explained in the book *La filologia romanza* by Pietro G. Beltrami, Latin /h/ was lost everywhere in the Romance domain and has left no trace in the Romance languages. So I suppose that this /h/ was acquired at a certain point in the history of Romanian. Can someone explain this? Is that to be attributed to the Slavic superstratum?

Answer (score 5):

All examples in the article are of Slavic origin: e.g. duh & hrean.

Also note *Slavic loanwords spread the consonant "h" in Common Romanian* in [Slavic influence on Romanian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavic_influence_on_Romanian):

> The majority of specialists say the consonant "h" was alien to Common
> Romanian, but borrowings from Slavic languages—like duh ("spirit")
> from *duxŭ, and hrean ("horseradish") from *xrĕnŭ—enabled its
> appearance in Romanian.

Comment: it's interesting that there don't appear to be any words of Albanian origin (or a variety more closely related to Albanian than any other surviving language) given the extent of contact there. I wonder if this can be used to periodise the development of h in Albanian (it either being early, having become glottal before Romanian lost Classical Latin h; or being late having still been VsV, sk, or ks at the time of borrowing)

Comment: @Tristan I’d say that mostly just shows that the contact from Slavic was much more intense than that from some relative of Albanian.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer I don't see why that would follow. Besides, we know contact between pre-Romanian and pre-Albanian _was_ intense, as evidenced by the fact that the Venn diagram of Balkan-sprachbund features present in Albanian and Romanian is almost a circle, much closer than between Romanian and the South Slavic languages

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer - The absence of `h` in Albanian and its omnipresence (and naturalness) in Romanian shows the strong Slavic lexical impact on Romanian compared to that impact on Albanian - but it doesn't show that the impact of the "Albanian-relative" on Romanian was weak. And it is consistent with the idea that Slavic invasions is what separated the Romanian and Albanian linguistic areas.